# naming standards/conventions and what should a 'Service' class should do

Tags: design-patterns, naming-conventions

What would you name a class which does only a very small part of functionality, for example taking a recurring payment profile and marking it as 'failed'.

Is it correct to name it `RecurringPaymentProfileMarkAsFailedService`? I know it's just a name, but I would like to adher to standards / convention.  Is this what a 'Service' class should do, or is this a different design pattern?  I am trying to follow up on the line of the SRP principle, and thus if I am correct one would end up with a lot of small classes, each specialised in one task.  I would like to define a correct naming standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I've never seen it strictly documented, I typically use the word 'Service' to indicate a class that handles some subset of related end-user functionality.

For example, say I have a bank account system, I might have the following service:

```
public class AccountService
{
  public boolean transfer(Account src, Account dest, double amt) // ....

  public Account create(User user, double initAmt) // ...

  public void close(Account account) // ...
}
```

So the "high-level" functions that the user can do are encapsulated in my Services.  Services will access the database, instantiate whatever helpers, do calculations, etc that it needs.  But like I said, this is just what I've observed from my time in the industry.

As far as SRP:  SRP does not mean that you need a whole new class for each function you want to perform.  You don't need a class to mark a profile as failed and another to mark it as success and another to change the name of the profile and ...

SRP means that each class handles "one thing" but that "one thing" can be a set of closely related functions.  Another important OO design principle to consider is encapsulation.  That is, a class should minimize what it exposes to clients - only exposing what others need. If you are having tons of little classes that manage a PaymentProfile's internal state, you are exposing all of the details of PaymentProfile.  I'll give you a small example:

Let's say your PaymentProfile object has a boolean isSuccess.  Then your class RecurringPaymentProfileMarkAsFailedService does something like this:

```
 public class RecurringPaymentProfileMarkAsFailedService {
   public void mark(PaymentProfile profile)
   {
     profile.setSuccess(false);
   }
 }
```

Cool - everything's working great.  Now we get a feature request that not only can a PaymentProfile have statuses 'Success' and 'Failure', but now we need to support 'InternalError' which means some internal system crashed during the update.  We can no longer use a boolean, so we change our boolean isSuccess to an enum that can be one of: SUCCESS, FAILURE, ERROR.  Now we have to refactor our MarkAsFailedService.

This is a trivial refactor b/c it's just one class, but for a complex class tree, these refactors could echo all across a system.  It's a sign that I'm revealing too many implementation details about my PaymentProfile.  A class should be encapsulated so a change to it's implementation has little/no impact on it's clients.

Comment: What about mocking and test-driven development?  My main issue with having an almost class-per-functionality is that external dependencies can be more easily mocked.  For example, the `MarkAsFailure()` method might need to send a Notification about it.  If the notification is implemented as a `MarkAsFailureNotificationSender` class, this can be injected via constructor injection to the class having the `MarkAsFailure()`, and verifying calls on the mock.  Any thoughts/comments on this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for what it's worth, it sounds from your description like you are using the Command design pattern.

Usually when I find that the class names get too long, I use a package or path hierarchy instead. In this case it might be something like:

Package: commands.recurringPaymentProfile

Class: MarkAsFailed

So: Instead of "Service" I use "command", then group the ones that apply to recurringPaymentProfile in one package.

Comment: I don't know if this matches exactly the `Command` pattern.  I'm using Commands & CommandHandlers, and then 'inject' Decorators using SimpleInjector (IoC Container) to add Transaction and Concurrency checks, which I've found to be a very nice way to add such repetetive but required code.  For commands, I'm currently restricting them to just database code, and I do have another `MarkAsFailedCommand` which just marks the profile as failed and saves in db.  This 'Service' has other logic like calling the MarkAsFailed command, and sending a notification.

Comment: OK, sounds exciting :) Still, I would recommend trying out a package/hierarchy structure to manage the name length creep. Works for me. I really don't think there's any standard for dealing with this in general use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand the "spirit" of the SRP, but personally I think it's taking it overboard to conclude that you must therefore create a separate class for what should probably just be a method (MarkAsFailed) on RecurringPaymentProfileService (given that you describe this logic as "a very small part of functionality").

I think that often when you end up struggling over long unwieldy names like this, it's a signal that you haven't quite struck the right balance between competing principles in regard to your code structure.

My guiding principle is that the service should attempt to adhere to the SRP in the sense that it relates as exclusively as is practicable to dealing with (returning / acting upon) a particular business entity or process - e.g. PaymentProfiles. But my inclination is that in attempting to split out the service's internals to the nth degree, you'll probably end up violating a whole bunch of other principles.

Comment: Personall that's what I thought originally, but I've been experimenting with it and this, together with Dependency injection via constructor injection makes the code much much more unit-testable.  I think it is worth the additional 'hassle' to split classes into smaller ones, I'm just a bit confused about naming patterns and would like to adher to 'standards', rather than set my own.